# ASP.NET Ajax and Validator problem

Tags: asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I have a webform with a TextBox, SaveButton, RequiredFieldValidator, DataGrid and a paging button. They're all in a single UpdatePanel. SaveButton saves TextBox value to the database and refreshes the DataGrid. Paging button retrieves next n records and refreshes the DataGrid. The problem is, when I click paging button to refresh the DataGrid, RequiredFieldValidator fires. How can I make it fire only when I click SaveButton?

I have set EnableClientScript="true" and ControlToValidate="textBox1" for the validator.

Comment: This shouldn't happen with the default gridview pager. Are you using a custom pager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting CausesValidation=false of the paging button.

Answer (score 1):

Restrict the textbox validator and the save button to a [Validation Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx).